Imprimir automaticamente un reporte sin abrir vista previa
Buen día, estoy intentado que imprima automaticamente un reporte pero cuando le doy a mi boton imprimir me aparece la vista previa y tengo que darle manual en imprimir, quisiera que me ayuden para que pueda hacer que sea automatco. dejo mi codigo:
Código del botón:
private void imprimir_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   corte_cja_class cortecc = new corte_cja_class();
    corte_cja_form corte = new corte_cja_form();
    cortecc.Fecha = Fecha_Txt.Text;
    cortecc.Totalcaja = total_txt.Text;
    corte.cortec.Add(cortecc);
    corte.Show();
}

Codigo del reportviewer:
    public partial class corte_cja_form : Form
{
    public List <corte_cja_class> cortec = new List<corte_cja_class> ();
    public corte_cja_form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void corte_cja_form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear ();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", cortec));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}

Muchas gracias!
